# webapi.helppage package added but apiexplorer is not finding anything

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a `.NET 4.5 MVC 4` project which I have added the `webapi.helppage` package to it via NuGet.

Then added an `ApiController` to my project of the below:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

to see if the help page is working, but it returns an empty `apidescription` collection for the below `GetApiExplorer()` call:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions);
    }
```

I can however use the example api controller by navigating to `/api/values` for example.

Anyone know why the `apidescription` wouldn't be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a new web api project and started adding in my installed NuGet packages one by one and it turns out `Glimpse` is what is causing these not to display.

I found more information here: [ASP.Net Web API Help Page returning empty output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958959/asp-net-web-api-help-page-returning-empty-output)

and the most appropriate work around so far is to add the below to the `web.config` glimpse section:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
<inspectors>
      <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Inspector.RoutesInspector, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
      </ignoredTypes>
    </inspectors>
</glimpse>
```