# Swashbuckle doesn't see any of my controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle

I had ASP MVC 5 project, to which I've added Web Api. Now I'm trying to install Swashbuckle (from bootstrap) - but it just shows an empty document without any controllers.

My controller:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/v1/Test/Check")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Test
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET: api/Test/5
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST: api/Test
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT: api/Test/5
        [HttpPut]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/Test/5
        [HttpDelete]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }

        // GET: api/Test
        [Route("GetMetadata")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> GetMetadata()
        {
            return new string[] { "value2221", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

My Web Api Config:

```
  configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

  configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Public API V1", "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

My `Global.asax.cs`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
```

`Swashbuckle` configuration is default.

The generated swagger document looks like this:

```
{
  swagger: "2.0",
  info: {
    version: "v1",
    title: "WebServer"
  },
  host: "localhost:55309",
  schemes: [
    "http"
  ],
  paths: { },
  definitions: { }
}
```

I can access my controller on `http://localhost:55309/api/v1/Test`

I'm not sure do I need to change anything in the generated `SwaggerConfig.cs` but looking through it and on `swashbuckle` docs it looks like it should work without any modifications

Comment: you have to put appropriate Attribute on your methods  , like HttpPost , HttpGet. try this

Comment: @osmanRahimi unfortunately doesn't make any difference. Still doesn't work

Comment: @Archeg please show us your attempt at using those attributes.  we can't help with what we can't see.

Comment: I think you problem is "ASP MVC 5 project" try just with a fresh default WebApi project and add swashbuckle

Comment: @HelderSepu Could be, but I need ASP MVC 5 + Web Api, so this is a no go. It works if I do it on a separate Web Api only project

Comment: @Amy Here you are. But I really doubt it has anything to do with attributes. As I said controller is working, it's only swashbuckle that doesn't see it

Comment: Yeah, nothing in your question stands out as the culprit.  I notice that your controller isn't called `Test` **`Api`** `Controller`, but that shouldn't be relevant.  As far as I'm aware, your question covers all the bases.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that you will need to compare the code (specifically the WebApiConfig.cs that's where all the config and routes are set) from a fresh default WebApi project and yours see what stands out.

Comment: @Amy Thanks for your support, if you are interested - please see my answer. I'm still not following the root of the problem (your inputs are welcome), but I finally made it work

Comment: @HelderSepu Thanks for your support, if you are interested - please see my answer. I'm still not following the root of the problem (your inputs are welcome), but I finally made it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I've made it. I had to download `swashbuckle` sources and debug it, but it was worth it.

Turns out the problem is not `swashbuckle` itself, but rather `ApiExplorer` that has `.ApiDescriptions` empty for some reason.

During my debug I've put these two lines in the end of my `Application_Start()`, and even though these lines don't do anything, magic happened and it started to work:

```
var explorer = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();
var descriptions = explorer.ApiDescriptions;
```

Then I went futher and found this topic: [ASP.Net Web API Help Page Area returning empty output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413786/asp-net-web-api-help-page-area-returning-empty-output) (see first answer)
I was using `Glimpse`, although I actually installed it in an attempt to solve the `swashbuckle` problem! (I thought it might help - it does not, but Glimpse felt a nice tool so I left it there)

As the first answer suggests, I've modified `web.config` with this:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
<inspectors>
   <ignoredTypes>
      <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Inspector.RoutesInspector, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
   </ignoredTypes>
</inspectors>
</glimpse>
```

And removed the two lines from `Application_Start()` as these are not a fix. It started to work!

To be honest I have no idea what is happening there. I clearly remember it not working before I started to use `Glimpse`, so installing a glimpse and fixing a problem in it doesn't feel like a proper fix to original problem, but I'm really tired of this issue and am ready to close it down like this.

Hope this helps somebody.

P.S. Just a warning to those who try to debug similar problems. My other mistake was that I didn't close IIS Express between my tries. It actually keeps application running so the configuration is not re-applied even though you start/stop app in VS. If you working with configuration - you need to close ISS Express between your tries.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem in my web api project and I have solved it this way:

1) First of all I have created the following extension method:

```
 public static class SwaggerExtensions
{
    public static HttpConfiguration EnableSwagger(this HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
    {
        httpConfiguration
            .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "WebApi"))
            .EnableSwaggerUi();
        return httpConfiguration;
    }
}
```

2) Then inside Startup class:

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.EnableSwagger();
        var webApiConfiguration = WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        //here I commented other startup code

    }
```